# Using PostRequestHandlerExecute, Flush and Close to clean up after a request - why is this bad?

Tags: asp.net

After some requests I need to clean up after the user - by calling a remote web service to release some resources if I guess the user doesn't need them anymore. It is ok to leave them hanging and letting them time out on the other server, but the polite thing to do is to inform it that I do not need them anymore.

I do not want to waste the users time waiting for cleaning - so I tried to find place to put it. First I tried Application_EndRequest, but I needed something later. Then I found PostRequestHandlerExecute which seemed like a nice place, but I still need a Flush and Close to release the connection to the user.

**THIS DON'T WORK ON MY SERVER ONLY WHEN DEBUGGING IN VISUAL STUDIO 2008!**

On the server pages become blank - if i remove the Flush and Close it works, but the user has to wait for the cleanup.

```
Protected Sub Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.Close()

        ' Simulation of clean up activity:
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(4000) ' Really a couple of web service calls
End Sub
```

Is there some other place I could put these lengthy clean up routines?
Is spawning another thread a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I think that the architecture you have decided upon sounds like it could need a rework.

To manually close resources gives me a bed feeling.

With that said I would suggest to start a thread to have the cleaning up done asynchronously via a delegate.